# C++ Modulus gives wrong output for -9%10

Tags: c++

I have a small code, the mod works fine for first iteration but on second iteration it fails.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;



int main() {
    string a = "acbdgd$&gf";
    string b = a;
    int size = a.size();
    int skip = 0;
    int ind;
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ind = (-i - 1) % size; // first time it give 0 as experted but in second run it gives -9
        char c = a[ind];
        if (c == '&' || c == '$') {
            skip++;
        }
        c = a[i];
        if (c == '&' || c == '$') {
            //b[i] = a[i];
        }
        else {
            b[ind + skip] = a[i];
        }
    }

    cout << a << endl << b;
}
```

The value of i is 8, -8-1 = -9 (tested by printing). -9 mod 10 = 1
But it gives -9.
I tried on 2 compilers, one g++ and other is Visual Studio.
The Variables state at time where the ind becomes -9 is
[image]

Comment: It is really confusing that every one calls the `%` operator "modulo", because it is not the mathematical modulo operator (only for positive operands)

Comment: Signed remainder operation have been traditionally been implementation defined for negative values. There is an issue with the standard but I can't seem to find when and in which standard it has been included. What version of the compilers are you using? What C++ standard are you targeting?

Comment: For well-defined behavior use [`std::div`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude follow the links to the duplicates, you'll see some discussion about that.  Seems like C++11.

Comment: Thanks, now I know the problem and will implement it myself